# How to insert a document to MongoDB if a compound key is not present using Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following class:

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SomeCollection {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String ordId;
  private String invoiceNum;
...
}
```

I only want to be able to insert a document to the collection if the combination of `ordId` and `invoiceNum` is unique and not yet present in the database.
For Example:

```
1. INSERT: ordId: 1, invoiceNum: "test"
2. INSERT: ordId: 2, invoiceNum: "test"
3. INSERT: ordId: 1, invoiceNum: "test3"
4. INSERT: ordId: 1, invoiceNum: "test2" 
5. INSERT: ordId: 2, invoiceNum: "test"
6. INSERT: ordId: 1, invoiceNum: "test"
7. INSERT: ordId: 5, invoiceNum: "test"
```

This will result in adding 5 documents to the collection, because insert 5 and insert 6 could be found in the existing collection, therefore these 2 documents won't be inserted.

I know that I can achieve that by querying the database with these values but I want to achieve this with `@annotations`

Answer (score 0):

There is no annotation which lets you define a composite primary key or does some magic which handles this for you automatically.

MongoDB requires you to have exactly one id field! Fortunately this field can be a nested document which could contain your key fields.

### Solution with MongoDB 'composite primary key'

If all your documents in the 'someCollection' collection are identified by `ordId` and `invoiceNum` and you do not need a separate id you can drop the autogenerated string id and move the two identifying fields into a nested document which is the id.

```
@Data
public class SomeCollection {
    @Id
    private Key key;

    @Value
    public static class Key {
        String ordId;
        String invoiceNum;
    }
}
```

With this solution you will not have to query and find existing documents in the collection before you save to avoid duplicate entries.
This is a bit uncomfortable to use in the rest of your application but you can always treat this as an implementation detail of your repository and convert it to a model/dto with the fields unwinded from the key sub-class/nested-document